# How to start work with Gmail API in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmail-api

I would like to add Gmail to my Rails 4 app. So far I have set up everything so user can log in with Google account. I followed this [guide](https://richonrails.com/articles/google-authentication-in-ruby-on-rails).

Now when user tries to log in my Rails 4 app he receives such onscreen :

[image]
After "Allow" user is redirected back to my Rails 4 app.

**Initializers/omioauth.rb**

```
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, Rails.application.secrets.client_id, Rails.application.secrets.client_secret, {scope: ['email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify'],
    access_type: 'offline', client_options: {ssl: {ca_file: Rails.root.join("cacert.pem").to_s}}}
end
```

All authorization data from Google is located in secrets.yml.

**Installed gems:**

```
gem "omniauth-google-oauth2", "~> 0.2.1"
gem "google-api-client"
```

**Question**: What are the next steps to implement Gmail API in Rails project? How to retrieve my Gmail inbox content..
So far I haven't found complete and self-explaining guide to do so.

I found [Gmail](https://github.com/gmailgem/gmail) gem, but the guide is very incomplete for Rails begginers.

For example, I installed this gem and then tried to `require 'gmail'` in `rails c` . Then I received error `uninitialized constance 'gmail'`.

Note: I don't need full solution to my problem,but just a push to start going and I could understand idea.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to check the [Ruby implementation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/ruby) of Gmail API in the Google Documentation itself.
Just complete the steps described in the rest of this page, and you'll have a simple Ruby command-line application that makes requests to the Gmail API.

For more information, you can also check these threads:

- [How to access the Gmail API with Ruby](http://readysteadycode.com/howto-access-the-gmail-api-with-ruby)
- [google/google-api-ruby-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client)
- [Gmail API Client Library for Ruby](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/apis/gmail/v1)
- [Gmail API and Rails – Authorize with OAuth via Omniauth](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/09/gmail-api-oauth-rails.html)